# Error while deleting partition

Tags: partitioning

I am new to Ubuntu. Using 16.04 LTS. Have changed from Windows 7 so I have no idea about command lines etc. Have little knowledge of technicalities of software.

In my partition window it shows

[image: Error message]

The partition is of 0.0 Kb. I don't know how it came there.

It reads thus

"Error deleting partion

Error deleting partition /dev/sdb3: Command-line `parted --script "/dev/sdb" "rm 3"' exited with non-zero exit status 1: Warning: Partition /dev/sdb3 is being used. Are you sure you want to continue?
 (udisks-error-quark, 0) "

Then there is no 'Ok' button also so that I can continue?

How to delete this partition?

Comment: Can you try this from terminal `sudo umount /dev/sdb3`. Close disks utility and open it again and try to delete partition.

Comment: as a side note: I'm against using gnome-disks for partitioning. Use gparted instead

Comment: You can't delete a partition that is in use.